# Linux raid autodetect (fd) or Linux RAID (ee)

Tags: raid, mdadm

Ubuntu 20.04 up to date.

I'm trying to setup a raid with 8TB disks and I'm following this guide using fdisk
https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/linux-software-raid-1-setup

I can't change partition type to fd. When I type fd and press enter the response is
"Partition type unchanged"

I listed all types and there is "Linux RAID" but not "Linux raid autodetect" and "Linux RAID" is "type ee"

I chose Linux RAID and when I check with gparted the raid flag is checked.

Am I good to go?
Why can't I choose fd?
What is the difference between fd and ee? Disk size?

Comment: Please add exactly what commands you ran to your question. You said you followed that guide exactly but that guide allows for different choices depending on if you used MBR or GPT label. Also, modern Linux [doesn't use the partition type at all](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Partition_Types) when assembling mdadm arrays so it doesn't really matter, beyond not confusing yourself or other software.

Answer (score 0):

sudo fdisk /dev/sd#
Follow these instructions.

Type n to create a new partition.
Type p to select primary partition.
Type 1 to create /dev/sd#1.
Press Enter to choose the default first sector
Press Enter to choose the default last sector. This partition will span across the entire drive.
Typing p will print information about the newly created partition. By default the partition type is Linux.
We need to change the partition type, so type t.
Enter fd to set partition type to Linux raid autodetect.
Type p again to check the partition type.
Type w to apply the above changes.

(https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/linux-software-raid-1-setup)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial, prior to start using fdisk, they label the disk with parted as DOS. Have you skipped that step?, if you create a new label for that disk (DOS partition table, using fdisk for example but you can also follow the tutorial and use parted), then create a new partition and then list all of the partition types, you will get the desired 'fd' between the results.

If the disks instead have a GPT partition table, you won't find 'fd', but numbers from 1 to 108 (fdisk version in Debian 11 repos) for each of the possible partition types.

Hope this helps.